# Mono doOnEmpty in Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

Is there any operator on `Mono` that would allow me to log fact that mono was empty?

I cannot use `hasElement()` because I need result and I don't want to introduce hacky solutions like abusing `switchIfEmpty`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`doOnSuccess`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnSuccess-java.util.function.Consumer-) and test if data is null

```
.doOnSuccess(data -> {
    if (data == null) {
        //onEmpty behavior
    }
})
```

Comment: note that `doOnSuccess` is only valid if the desired behavior is indeed a side effect (like updating some metrics or something like that). it is for example highly undesirable to call another `Flux`/`Mono` `subscribe`, as it would prevent said publisher to propagate its errors to the main sequence. but `switchIfEmpty` should work in that case (as it only acts if the source is effectively empty, otherwise keeping the source value)

Answer (score 1):

The issue that the OP is describing is missing functionality in the module (imo). Whether you do:

```
.switchIfEmpty(
  Mono.defer(() -> {
    //onEmpty behavior
    return Mono.empty();
  })
)
```

or what the accepted answer is:

```
.doOnSuccess(data -> {
  if (data == null) {
    //onEmpty behavior
  }
})
```

(`.doOnEach` is similar to `.doOnSuccess`, except it also fires on error signals)

Neither method name really describes the purpose of the code block, which is to only fire on an empty signal. It makes it more time consuming to browse code when debugging issues.